# How to prevent slow printer performance when AD is not available

Tags: active-directory, printing

When I take a domain based computer (Windows XP) and plug it into a network that doesn't have access to the AD, the first time I select a local printer (printing directly to printer) on the current network it takes a good 20-30 seconds before I can select the printer.  Doing a little investigating using wireshark I can see the computer is trying to hit AD for some reason and it just keeps timing out.  I also tried the same experiment with just a plain workgroup computer and it was able to bring the printer up immediately.  Does anyone know how to prevent the machine from trying to contact AD?

Comment: The printer is not shared or published in AD.

Comment: Are you logging in with cached credentials, or a local account?

Answer (score 0):

Manually add the printer using a local TCP/IP port. This will make your client to point directly to the printer IP but of course you will lose the printer server queue management advantages as you are printing directly to printer.

Regards, D.